# Can NPCs jump on wooden planks?

Tags: terraria

I don't know how to get my NPCs into their house if it is above another NPC's house. I don't exactly know if they can jump on to wooden planks but it doesn't seem like they can. I want them to be able to go inside their houses without me making stairs every night.

Answer (score 6):

This is a known bug with the last PC version of Terraria (version 1.1.2). All NPCs (both friendly and enemy) are **unable to use wooden platforms** when pathfinding. They will never jump up on them; friendly NPCs will also never fall down through them.

You can abuse this by putting NPC rooms in your town only on non-ground floors, with wooden platforms as the only way to get from one floor to another. After you've built the rooms this way, spend a full (in-game) night far away from your house, and the NPCs will all teleport to their rooms. Since they can't use the platforms to change floors, and the floors they're on have no exit to the outside, they'll never go outside to be killed by slimes again. Very convenient!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy to have NPC's go down to your main room and back to their own rooms. They can just get anywhere, up and down. No switches, electronics, mods or hoists needed. Only woodplatforms and a building. Wanted to share the way I did it because I could not find the near-perfect way without switches or hoist.

[image]

I opened all doors so they move faster. They open it less often on their own. But this works regardless of open or closed doors.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help]; they're a useful introduction to the site. Arqade isn't a forum and answer posts are not for general discussion, only for attempts to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, NPC's will use wooden platforms to go to their rooms or to climb up on steep terrain etc.

I use your setup myself in houses and it works quite fine:

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure they just teleported into their rooms when they were off screen during the night and didn't actually use the platforms.

Answer (score 1):

They can walk on them but I've seen them jump onto just a platform. They only jump onto solid blocks. So no they can't.

Also, they will just teleport to their home if you wait long enough. You could also kill the NPC with lava if they get stuck or something. Then they should re-spawn in their home.

Comment: But can they jump onto wooden planks?

Comment: I don't think they can. Not sure.

Comment: They can walk on them but I've seen them jump onto just a platform. They only jump onto solid blocks. So to answer the original question, no they can't.

Comment: Ok. Maybe put that answer into your answer then? Answering the question in the answer post is kinda how we roll 'round here.

Comment: I make no stairs and use only wooden platforms and they actually do go to their rooms.

Answer (score -1):

It *seems like* that they can't enter the houses, but if you wait long enough after they arrive, they will just teleport to their homes no matter where. There is something to consider tho. İf you are making houses on top of each other, DON'T make their walls shared. Don't use one houses ceiling as the other's floor.

Comment: I'm assuming you are meaning double layering the construction material of your choice for the floor/ceiling part of your answer, otherwise I have no bloody clue why you shouldn't do this

Comment: Why shouldn't we use shared walls?

Comment: [Having a shared floor/ceiling is fine.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3QnOw.jpg)

Comment: But can they jump onto wooden planks?