# How do you make stacked houses?

Tags: terraria

I have a stacked house where there are houses on each side of a vertical tunnel, with wood platforms to separate the floors. None of the NPCs on the second floor will jump onto the platform and into their house. The houses are all 5 tiles high. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the rooms are acceptable for NPC's to move in then the problem is NPC's will only jump 3 tiles high. You will need a sort of stair case, but even then it isn't garaunteed they will go to their rooms. If the rooms aren't acceptable then too much of the floor is made of platforms. The flooring must contain a certain number of solid bricks to make it a room.

Comment: I answered this question previously: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112230/can-npcs-jump-on-wooden-planks/112431#112431. TLDR: a bug was introduced in like 1.0.9 that made NPCs unable to use wooden platforms, at all. It's one of the things that caused me to quit.

Answer (score 1):

The NPCs once added to a house (assuming it reads housing suitable) will not necessarily be there however you can try quitting and restarting or walking away from your house for a while. even if the NPC is not in the house the bonuses will still be applied as long as housing reads suitable.

Remember:

houses need light source, door, chair, and table
houses need to be enclosed
need at least one solid block on floor (not platform)
need to be X high and X long for NPCs to live their

Comment: The roof needs to be 5 blocks high, and the interior of the house needs to be 8 blocks long, so 10 blocks if you count the walls. The best way to tell if you did it right is if 32 walls fill the house completely.

Answer (score 0):

I think VanBuzzKill has it.  Here was my solution to not having NPC's able to reach the various levels of the apartments.

[Apartment Complex](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=210357154) and it even has The Rotten Pumpkin bar and grill(tm)...